# DHPublicKey is not recognized

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

My public key's class is: `com.sun.crypto.provider.DHPublicKey`

When I try to run DH `dophase()` method it gives this error:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Diffie-Hellman public key expected

Isn't my public key is already Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: Could you show some code and the version of the Java runtime please?

Comment: Are you using the same security provider for the KeyPairGenerator and the KeyAgreement on both Clients?